# FFMPEG. Combine rawAudio and rawVideo from named pipe

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have 2 NamedPipeServerStreams. 1 for Audio (Stereo Mix). I am using WavIn from NAudio and 1 for Video (Screen Capture). Just converting BitBlt screen to Byte Array.

I'm able to create an mp4 video for the rawvideo and changing code, a seperate wav for the rawaudio but am unable to combine/merge both into an mp4 video.

These are the ffmpeg commands i'm using.

To create the audio wav file:

```
string args = @"-f s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i \\.\pipe\ffpipea -c copy output.wav";
```

Audio plays really fast but it at least gets it.

To create the video mp4 file:

```
string inputArgs = @"-framerate 8 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\ffpipev";
string outputArgs = "-vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 8 output.mp4";
```

My attempt to combine/merge both:

```
string args = @"-framerate 8 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\ffpipev " +
        @"-f s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i \\.\pipe\ffpipea " +
        "-map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 8 -c:a copy output.mp4";
```

Depending on what i change in the args, either the WaitForConnection() never fires or the audiopipe breaks with pip is broken.

Please let me know if i can provide further information. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: ffmpeg won't mux PCM into MP4. Change `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac`. Audio speed mismatch is due to incorrect input parameter, usually sampling rate.

Comment: Thanks Gyan. That did the trick. Needed to tweak some audio settings to get audio that didn't sound like a chipmunk. Now onto the sync issues. Appreciated. How do i mark this as answered by you?